# Showing two Joint Random Variables are Independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two random variables, $X,Y\sim$ Geo$(p)$.  Define two more random variables, $U=\min{(X,Y)}$ and $V=X-Y$.  I am tasked with showing that $U$ and $V$ are independent.

This means I need the joint distribution $f_{U,V}(u,v)$.  So

$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=P(U=u,V=v)=P(\min{(X,Y)}=u, X-Y=v)$$

This is confusing me.  So i thougth I look at the support of $U$ and $V$.  Since $X,Y$ is geometric, then the minimum of $X$ and $Y$ is also over the same support of $X$ and $Y$ which would just be $\mathbb{N}$.  But the support of $V$ would then be $\mathbb{Z}$ since $V$ can take on negative values ($x=3, y=4$, for example).  So do I need to consider cases of $V$ then and compare the distributions of all three?

For example, if $V>0$, then $X>Y$ and $\min{(X,Y)}=Y$.  If $V<0$, then $Y>X$ and $\min{(X,Y)}=X$.  For the first case,

$$V>0\Rightarrow  P(\min{(X,Y)}=u, X-Y=v)=P(Y=u, X=v+y)=P(X=v+u,Y=u)$$

So since $X,Y$ are independent,

$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=P(X=v+u,Y=u+v)=P(X=u+v)P(Y=u)=p(1-p)^{u+v}p(1-p)^u$$

So $f_{U,V}(u,v)=p^2(1-p)^{2u+v}$.  Is this correct? And is this the correct approach to now consider $V<0$ and then $V=0$?

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: so once I consider all three cases and show that I can decomopse the three joint distributions into the product of functions in $U$ and $V$, this is sufficient prove the independence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U$ and $V$ are independent if and only if $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ can be written as 
$f(u)f(v)$.

Now our variables are 
$$
X = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}  U&V\geq 0\\
U+V& V<0\end{array}\right.\\
Y = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}  U-V&V\geq 0\\
U& V<0\end{array}\right.
$$
Then using our knowledge of $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ we can fill in  $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ as
$$
 f_{U,V}(u,v) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}  (1-p)^{u-1}p(1-p)^{u-v-1}p &v\geq 0\\
(1-p)^{u+v-1}p(1-p)^{u-1}p & v<0\end{array}\right.
$$
and these expressions can be written as 
$$
 f_{U,V}(u,v) =   (1-p)^{2u+|v|-2}p^2 
= \left[(1-p)^{2u-1}p \right] \left[(1-p)^{|v|-1}p \right]=f(u)f(v)
$$