# For random variables $U$ and $W$, Find $P(U=i)$ and $P(W=j)$ for $i,j=0,1,\dots$.

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with the same geometric distribution $P(X=k)=P(Y=k)=(1-p)p^k$ for $k=0,1,\dots, $. Let $U=\min\{X, Y\}$ and $V=\max\{X, Y\}$ and $W=V-U$.

(a) Find $P(U=i)$ and $P(W=j)$ for $i,j=0,1,\dots$.

(b) Show that $U$ and $W$ are independent.

---

My solution:

(a) For the first distribution, note that for $i=1,2,\dots$
$$
P(U=i)=P(U\le i)-P(U\le i-1).
$$

Since
$$
P(U\le i)=1-P(U>i)=1-P(X>i, Y>i)=1-(1-F(i))^2=1-p^{2i+2}
$$
where $F(i)=\sum_{k=0}^i (1-p)p^k=1-p^{i+1}$.

Hence, $P(U=i)=p^{2i}-p^{2i+2}$.

For the second distribution, note that for $j=1,2,\dots$,
$$
P(W=j)=P(W\le j)-P(W\le j-1).
$$

So it is enough to get
$$
P(W\le j)=P(V-U\le j)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(V\le U+j)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(V\le U+j|U=i)P(U=i)
$$
$$
=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(V\le i+j)P(U=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(F(i+j))^2P(U=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-p^{i+j+1})^2(p^{2i}-p^{2i+2}).
$$

Is there a problem with my (a) asking where it was done? Also, I can't further simplify...

(b) To prove this one, we need to get
$$
P(U=i, W=j)=P(V=i+j)=P(V\le i+j)-P(V\le i+j-1).
$$

Note that
$$
P(V\le i+j)=P(X\le i+j, Y\le i+j)=[F(i+j)]^2=(1-p^{i+j+1})^2
$$

Comment: '$P(V-U\le j)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(V\le U+j)$...' ? Note that $V-U=|X-Y|$ and find its pmf directly. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2685256/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom How to get $P(|X-Y|=j)$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Does this one $P(U=i)=P(U\le i)-P(U\le i-1)$ right?