How to show the range is independent of the smallest order variable?
I am studying order statistics in An Intermediate Course in Probability by Gut. First the author treats only continuous distributions. In a section on the joint distribution of the extreme order variables $X_{(n)}=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ and $X_{(1)}=\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$, the author derives the density of the range. that is $R_n=X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$. Then there's the following exercise:

Exercise 2.5 The geometric distribution is a discrete analog of the exponential distribution in the sense of lack of memory. More precisely, show that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent $\text{Ge}(p)$-distributed random variables, then $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}$ are independent.

What I find confusing about this exercise is that the author has, up until now, not derived any results for order statistics when it comes to discrete distributions. I know the formula for the density of $X_{(1)}$ and the range when the underlying distribution is continuous, but these do not apply for discrete distribution. I was thinking going back to an earlier chapter where the author derives distributions of transformations of random variables. I was thinking I could assume $X_2$ to be greater than $X_1$ and then compute the pmf of their difference, but this doesn't feel like a sensible assumption, since after all, $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is understood pointwise.
How would you approach solving this exercise?

Wikipedia was helpful, but it doesn't elaborate on what the joint pmf of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}$ could be. I suppose one would need this in order to compute the pmf for the range.

$X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}$ is just $|X_1-X_2|$, and you can use https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2685256/321264.

Assuming Geometric$(p)$ is supported on $\mathcal{N}=\lbrace 0,1,2,\dots \rbrace$, and denoting $\mathcal{Z}^+=\lbrace 1,2,\dots\rbrace$,
$$\begin{align}
P\left[X_{(1)}=u\right] 
&=P(X_1=X_2=u)+P(X_1=u,X_2>u)+P(X_2=u,X_1>u)\\
&=P(X_1=u)^2 +2 P(X_1=u)P(X_2>u) \\
&=\left(p^2(1-p)^{2u} + 2 p(1-p)^u\ (1-p)^{u+1} \right)I_{\mathcal{N}}(u) \\
&=(1-p)^{2u}p(2-p)\ I_{\mathcal{N}}(u) . \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}P\left[X_{(1)}=u, X_{(2)}=u+d \right] \\
&=\left[ P(X_1=u, X_2=u+d) + P(X_1=u+d, X_2=u)\right]I(d>0) \\
&\quad\quad + P(X_1=X_2=u)I(d=0) \\
&= 2P(X_1=u+d, X_2=u)I(d>0)+P(X_1=X_2=u)I(d=0) \\
&= p^2(1-p)^{2u}\left[ 2(1-p)^d I_{\mathcal{Z}^+}(d) + I(d=0)\right] \  I_{\mathcal{N}}(u) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
P\left[X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}=d \right] 
&=\left[ P(X_1-X_2=d) + P(X_2-X_1=d)\right]I_{\mathcal{Z}^+}(d) \\
&\qquad + P(X_1=X_2)I(d=0) \\
&= 2\mathbb{E}\left[ P(X_1=X_2+d\mid X_2)\right] I_{\mathcal{Z}^+}(d) \\
&\qquad +\mathbb{E}\left[ P(X_1=X_2\mid X_2) \right]I(d=0) \\
&= 2\mathbb{E}\left[ p(1-p)^{X_2+d}\right] I_{\mathcal{Z}^+}(d) + \mathbb{E}\left[p(1-p)^{X_2}\right]I(d=0)\\
&=p\left[2(1-p)^d I_{\mathcal{Z}^+}(d)+I(d=0)\right]\mathbb{E}\left[ (1-p)^{X_2}\right]\\
&= p\left[2(1-p)^d I_{\mathcal{Z}^+}(d)+I(d=0)\right] (2-p)^{-1} \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}$$
Now equation \eqref{2} is a product of \eqref{1} and \eqref{3} for all $u$ and $d$, implying independence of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}$.

For $d\geq0$, the memoryless property is usually stated as
$$P(X>u+d\mid X\geq u) = \frac{P(X>u+d)}{P(X\geq u)}=\frac{(1-p)^{u+d+1}}{(1-p)^{u}}=(1-p)^{d+1}=P(X>d),$$
which is free of $u$.
Thus, $P(X_2>X_1+d,\ X_2\geq X_1)=P(X_2>d)P(X_2\geq X_1)$.
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
P\left[X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}>d\right]&=2P(X_2-X_1>d) \\
&=2\left[P(X_2>X_1+d,\ X_2\geq X_1)+ P(X_2>X_1+d,\ X_2 < X_1) \right]\\
&=2\left[ P(X_2>d)P(X_2\geq X_1) + 0 \right]\\
&=2 (1-p)^{d+1} \frac{1+P(X_1=X_2)}2\\
&=\frac{2(1-p)^{d+1}}{2-p}.
\end{align}$$
But
$$P\left[X_{(1)}>u\right]=P(X_1>u)P(X_2>u)=(1-p)^{2(u+1)}.
$$
Their joint probility is
$$\begin{align}
P\left[X_{(1)}>u,\ X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}>d \right]&=
2P\left[X_1>u,\ X_2-X_1>d \right] \\
&=2\sum_{k=u+1}^\infty P(X_1=k, X_2>k+d)\\
&=2p(1-p)^{d+1} \sum_{k=u+1}^\infty(1-p)^{2k} \\
&=2p(1-p)^{d+1} \frac{(1-p)^{2(u+1)}}{2p-p^2}\\
&=\frac{2(1-p)^{2u+d+3}}{2-p}.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $$P\left[X_{(1)}>u,\ X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}>d \right]=P\left[X_{(1)}>u\right]\ P\left[X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}>d\right].$$
